# Rating bar, how to get the number of stars?

Tags: java, android, xml, textwatcher, ratingbar

I got an edit text and also a rating bar in my program. I am checking if the user has more than 3 characters in the edit text and for rating bar it should have something greater than  0.5 star (basically to check if they at least clicked on any of them).

```
    final EditText commentbox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.comment);
    final RatingBar rating = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.rating);
    final Button feedbackbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);


    final TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            if(commentbox.length() >= 3 && rating.getNumStars() >=0.5){
                feedbackbutton.setEnabled(true);
                feedbackbutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#369742"));
            } else  {
                feedbackbutton.setEnabled(false);
                feedbackbutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffcacaca"));
            }


        }

    };
    commentbox.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    rating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener((this));
```

So as you can see it has to meet those condition in order for a button to become enabled and also to change its background colour. However soon as I write more than 3 characters in the edit text, the button enables itself and changes its colour. It's not looking for the rating bar condition.

Can someone help me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 feedbackbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){  

            @Override  
            public void onClick(View arg0) {  
                //Getting the rating and displaying it on the toast  
                String rating=String.valueOf(rating.getRating());  
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rating, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            }  

        });
```

Hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 4):

To get rating from rating value:

```
float ratingValue =  rating.getRating();
```

Add listener :

```
rating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar arg0, float rateValue, boolean arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("Rating", "your selected value is :"+rateValue);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks !